# How to create spinner animation with 12 steps (30deg each) from static PNG image?

Tags: react-native, animation

The goal is to create an animated spinner loader based on a custom PNG image.

**something like this**

[image]

The problem for me is to create rotation on 30deg each X time.
Not smoothly but step by step to emulate the original spinner.

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            spinValue: new Animated.Value(0)
        };
    }

    _animSteps = () => {
        let steps = 11
        let sequence = []
        let deg = 0

        for (let i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
            deg += 30
                sequence.push(
                    Animated.timing(
                        this.state.spinValue,
                        {
                            toValue: deg,
                            duration: 1000,
                            easing: Easing.linear,
                            useNativeDriver: true
                        }
                    )
                )
        }
        return sequence
    }
```

Render:

```js
Animated.loop(
    Animated.sequence(
        this._animSteps()
    )
).start()
```

```js
<Animated.Image
                            style={[s.loader, { transform: [{ rotate: this.state.spinValue }] }]}
                            source={require('loader.png')}/>
```

Comment: The easiest way would be using two images - one with holes (12 steps) and under it put gradient circle. Use css transform https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/transforms  to rotate the circle and you have what you need.

Comment: a few day ago while I was trying promises, I was thinking of using it or `setInterval `to draw the bars and dim it down by opacity or color, and each of the 12 bars is a rectangle with round corners. It might be fun to actually dim it down by one high frequency, and turn the wheel by a different (and possibly lower) frequency. If we don't care and let them be exactly the same frequency, it probably is fine to draw it once and simply to use transform rotate to achieve the effect

Comment: @Zydnar Hmm... Interesting idea, thank you. Just... Do u mean to use image/SVG like a mask?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            spinValue: new Animated.Value(0)
        };
    }

    render() {
        let seq = []
        for (let i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
            seq.push(Animated.timing(
                this.state.spinValue,
                {
                    toValue: i,
                    duration: 0,
                    easing: Easing.linear,
                    useNativeDriver: true
                }
            ))
            seq.push(Animated.delay(60))
        }
        Animated.loop(Animated.sequence(seq)).start()

        const spin = this.state.spinValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
            outputRange: ['0deg', '30deg', '60deg', '90deg', '120deg', '150deg', '180deg', '210deg', '240deg', '270deg', '300deg', '330deg', '360deg']
        })

            return (
                <View style={[s.container, this.props.style]}>
                    <View style={s.loaderHolder}>
                        <Animated.Image
                            style={[s.loader, { transform: [{ rotate: spin }] }]}
                            source={require(Image.Source)}/>
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
               }
```

Comment: Works great, thank you! Not sure why this is not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the code given below :

```
 state = {
    spinValue: new Animated.Value(0),
  }

 spin = () => {
    Animated.timing(
      this.state.spinValue,
      {
        duration: 1000,
        toValue: 1,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }
    ).start(() => this.reset());
  }

reset = () => {
    this.state.spinValue.setValue(0);
    return this.spin();
  }

componentDidMount () {
    this.spin();
  }

 render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            {
              transform: [
                {
                  rotate: this.state.spinValue.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                    outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
                  }),
                },
              ],
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Image source={Images.TestImg}/>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

- Though you will notice a small interruption of the animation since we need to reset the value to zero each time before we run it again